# Expected type 'collections.Iterable', got 'RasterImageExtensions'

Tags: python

Python 3.8.5

```
class RasterImageExtensions(Enum):
    WEBP = 'webp'
    PNG = 'png'
    JPG = 'jpg'
    TIFF = 'tif'

permitted_ext_type = RasterImageExtensions
permitted_extensions = [item.value for item in permitted_ext_type]
```

Expected result: ['webp', 'png', 'jpg', 'tif',].

**Problem**

permitted_ext_type is is underlined by a red wavy line in my IDE (Pycharm Community 2020.3).

The message.

> Expected type 'collections.Iterable', got 'RasterImageExtensions'
> instead   Inspection info: This inspection detects type errors in
> function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing,
> this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of
> function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3
> function annotations.
>
> Parameter permitted_ext_type of
> images.validators.FileValidator.validate_file_name_and_ext_according_to_field
> permitted_ext_type: RasterImageExtensions

[image]

This is about type checking. The program works executes any errors. And the expected result is achieved. But I confess zero tolerance for errors and warnings in IDE.

Enums are iterable: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/enum.html?highlight=enum#enum.Enum

In the very first paragraph:

> and the enumeration itself can be iterated over.

Could you help me with two questions:

1. Is it a bug in PyCharm?
2. If it is not a bug, how to refactor the code correctly?

Comment: Um, did you mean `permitted_ext_type = RasterImageExtensions`? The code you provided would throw a `NameError` otherwise.

Comment: Yes. Definitely the code line you mentioned is in the excerpt.

Comment: @Kifsif in your post you have a double equals for that line, not a single equals

Comment: Pardon. I've corrected it. Single equals is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem and I solved it by explicitly adding to the class definition the `metaclass` argument. You should just:

```
class RasterImageExtensions(Enum, metaclass=EnumType):
    WEBP = 'webp'
    PNG = 'png'
    JPG = 'jpg'
    TIFF = 'tif'
```

It definitely seems to be a PyCharm issue, since the metaclass already is `EnumType` by inheritance, but Pycharm doesn't seem to realize that, and you need a metaclass with `__iter__` defined for the class to be iterable. It assumes the metaclass is the default `type` and gives a warning.